# How to run nuget on Mac osx

Tags: c#, mono, steambot

I'm trying to open a Windows compiled c# solution in monodevelop on my Mac os x mountain lion, and the solution has nuget packages in it.

When I try to compile I get the following errors:

```
var/folders/bk/sqxq4pw50lsb807cw8x865gc0000gn/T/tmp4586d973.tmp: 
line 1: wget: command not found
/Users/(my name)/Downloads/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets: 
error : Command 'mozroots --import 
--sync;wget -O '/Users/(my name)/Downloads/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe'https://nuget.org/nuget.exe' 
exited with code: 127.
Task "Exec" execution -- FAILED
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

```
line 1: wget: command not found
```

The error is about 'wget' not existing. OS-X does not come with 'wget' out of the box (it has **curl**).

Use [homebrew](http://brew.sh) (my fav):

```
> brew install wget
```

Or Use [MacPorts](https://guide.macports.org):

```
> sudo port wget
```

Or manually install from [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

After you can execute 'which wget' or 'wget --version' and get a valid reply, try building your project again.

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried installing wget and I am getting a valid reply when I type wget --version but I still get the command not found error. What to do?

Comment: I cloned that repo and tried it on my mac, different problem for me as a custom nuget target is defined for ci and it is missing a script (.ci/exec-with-retry.sh). I would post a issue over on github.

Comment: I tried your answer, and I'm getting the same  error. The exec with retry thing. What to do

Comment: I would just remove that custom exec from the nuget target, assuming it is for CI only, not really needed for local builds

Comment: I tried doing that and I faced another error. A different one. Can I contact you via PM?

Comment: I removed the line from nuget.targets which said something about the exec-with-retry shell script. and when i try to build, i get this error

/Users/VISK/Desktop/BOTmaking/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets: error : Error executing task Exec: Required property 'Command' not set